# USB 3.0 port not working, works briefly after kernel updates only

Tags: grub2, usb, kernel, dell, inspiron

I have Dell Inspiron N5110 (2x USB-3 and 2x USB-2 ports) running Ubuntu 20.04.

I have an external drive that I use to boot Windows from in order to run some work related apps.

Whenever I plug the eHDD it just blinks as if the port is damaged, however, I noticed that after kernel updates, the USB port functions properly, I can boot to Windows, even do some Windows updates related reboots with no issues.

Then again after a while it stops working again.

I have an old bios that doesn't have IOMMU option.

I tried editing GRUB configuration (IOMMU edits and some other) but it didn't solve my problem.

I suspected its hardware failure as I have 2 other ports (1x USB-3 & 1x USB-2) that need replacement, but I think my issue here is something else as the port is not completely dead.

I don't know how installing a new kernel update is a temporary fix, maybe voltage related?

Comment: How many and what type of devices are plugged into the USB ports? Voltage-related issues can appear when the ports need to supply more power than it can get from the host. If this is a notebook, some manufacturers limit their USB ports to 3.3V output rather than 5V, which creates a whole host of long-term reliability issues.

Comment: A mouse connected to usb-2 port as the touchpad sucks, 
I recently added a cooler pad connected to the other non functional USB-2 (since all I need from it is electricity) but the issue started before it.
Also, when the USB-3 actually works and I'm able to use the eHDD, it works while the other devices are connected

Comment: I'd like to add that this model has a grounding issue, as I can get electric shock from touching any exposed metal part while touching the floor.

While the issue maybe related, I don't get how sometimes the ports work and then stops working, and why does it work after a kernel update?!